# Need help extracting 280 rar files located within 280 folders

Tags: rar

I hope this doesn't break rule 2.
I have a bunch of folders that all have a .rar in them and I need to extract all the files and place them in one directory. Is there an easier way to do this than by going into each directory individually?
what it looks like:
/dirA---->rar1; /dirB---->rar2; /dirC---->rar3 etc...

Comment: `find . -name '*.rar' -exec unrar x {} . \;`

Comment: Bah I was about to post that as an answer!

Comment: This question is still open, one of you should post it as an answer so we can vote on it. Also a little bit of an explanation on what exactly the find command is doing would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe with `xargs` command like that:

```
find . -name *.rar|xargs -I{} unrar {}
```

`find` shows the relative path for the rar files. `xargs` execute for each one unrar